# Травить анекдоты

Tags: фразеология

Как так случилось, что глагол "травить" во фразе "травить анекдоты" стал синонимом слову "рассказывать"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Травить анекдоты** — **рассказывать непрерывно** весь имеющийся запас анекдотов, "сливать" их понемногу.

Также:  **травить** (сливать) **баланду**.

БАЛАНДА, Разг. 1. Жидкая невкусная похлёбка. 2. **Пустой, беспредметный разговор, болтовня**. Кончай баланду, работать надо. Травить баланду (вести такие разговоры; болтать).

Из словаря:

2. ТРАВИТЬ,  что. Мор. **Выпускать, отпускать понемногу** (снасть, канат и т.п.), ослабляя натяжение. **Т. цепь. Т. канат.** 2. (св. стравить). что. Спец. Выпускать наружу (пар, воздух), ослабляя давление. Т. лишний воздух из скафандра.  воздуха.
3. ТРАВИТЬ, (что). Разг. **Рассказывать небылицы. Травили анекдоты весь вечер.** Кончай т.! Не трави - всё равно не поверим.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

О многозначности глагола ***травить.***

1) **Травить** — это уничтожать. И.-е. корень ter-, тот же, что в глаголе тереть, перетирать. ***Трава*** — это то, что съедается  (**уничтожается**) травоядными животными.

2) **Травить** — это выпускать, уменьшать (**уничтожать**) понемногу, постепенно.  Например, стравливать пар, травить канат (уменьшать его натяжение).

**3) Травить анекдоты**  — это непрерывно рассказывать анекдоты (стравливать их), тем самым уменьшая их запас.

Comment: Позвольте воспользоваться Вашим ответом, чтобы сделать пару комментариев :) Ещё есть техническое значение слова **травить** (см. травление металла, например). Кстати, в этом значении это слово впервые отмечено в письменных источниках в русском языке (в 1589 г.) Любопытно, что "точить лясы" тоже имеет буквальный "ремесленный" смысл. Кстати, Виноградов поэтому предполагал, что именно таким путём объясняется происхождение подобных выражений, но Мокиенко и некоторые другие его оспорили. Я тоже согласен, что в данном случае ошибался Виноградов.

Comment: Да, этимология слова **травить** восходит к **тереть**. И тут вспоминаются другие жаргонные выражения, означающие какие-то разговоры: *перетереть*, *тереть тёрки*. Интересно, является ли это случайным совпадением, или всё же как-то сказывается специфическое семантическое гнездо.

Comment: Может быть, у всех  разговоров, сводимых к ремесленным названиям, общим является  неисчерпаемый запас "материала", мало интересного и утомительного для слушателей.

Answer (score 3):

Современный русский литературный язык, Минск, Высшая школа, 2012

https://books.google.ru/books/content?id=x8x6DQAAQBAJ&hl=ru&pg=PA150&img=1&zoom=3&ots=RsJzs8Y72S&sig=ACfU3U2C8mwlBm4Jpb9YB9BrOrpusZJcNw&w=1280

*Фразеологические сращения, или идиомы - семантически неделимые, неразложимые устойчивые сочетания, значения которых воспринимаются как абсолютно немотивированные, независимые от значений их составных частей (бить баклуши, ... травить баланду).*

*Травить баланду* означает "вести пустой разговор". По всей видимости, родственное, модифицированное (конкретизированное) значение имеет и выражение "**травить анекдоты (байки)**" - рассказывать что-либо в порядке праздного времяпровождения, убивая время. Каков же здесь исходный смысл глагола **травить**? Он явно не таков, как в "словарных" же выражениях "*травить душу*" и "*травить сердце*" (значение "*отравлять*"). Можно предположить, что когда-то произошло перенесение сюда другого известного смысла: "**отпускать понемногу** (рыболовную снасть, канат)" - это есть ещё у Брокгауза и Ефрона. Само слово "*отпускать*" широко используется по отношению к *шуткам или замечаниям*. Поэтому логично предположить, что и в нашем случае происходит неспешное и праздное (часто поочерёдное в компании) "отпускание" или даже "испускание из себя" того, что есть сказать от нечего делать. Это подтверждается и тем, что не существует выражения "стравить (один) анекдот" - всё дело в длительном процессе праздного времяпровождения, когда анекдоты рассказываются один за другим.

Answer (score 1):

Сразу скажу, что мой ответ неверный, ни на что не претендующий!

Но для себя я объясняю это выражение так: доставлять удовольствие рассказыванием анекдотов. Исхожу из значения слова ТРАФИТЬ:

ТРА́ФИТЬ, трафлю, трафишь, несовер. (к потрафить) ***(от нем. treffen - попадать***) (прост.).
1. без доп. Совершать что-нибудь удачно, ловко, так, как требуется.
2. кому-чему. Угождать, делать приятное, по вкусу, потрафлять.

Толковый словарь Ушакова. Д.Н. Ушаков. 1935-1940.

Comment: А "травить баланду" как Вы для себя объясняете?

Comment: Интересная точка зрения и у вас, Екатерина!

Answer (score 0):

Это когда через один анекдот дело идёт к другому. Эдакая затравка, подстрекание, поддержка друг друга в настроении.

Comment: А если "баланду травить" — тоже затравка для поддержки настроения?

Comment: Поддержка в настроении общаться, в настроении общения.

Comment: Вряд ли так "затравка" имеет к этому отношение. Скорее, по аналогии с травлей зайца — ходить бесконечно по кругу, рассказывая то ли анекдоты, то ли байки, то ли баланду.

Comment: Уточню. Обратите внимание на падеж. Не "травить анекдоТАМИ", а именно: "травить анекдоТЫ". В первом случае травят собеседника. Во втором - на анекдот должен последовать анекдот от собеседника, то есть имеется в виду не само подстрекание собеседника к беседе, а выуживание соответствующего анекдота (баланды, разговора).

Comment: Я не о том. Впрочем, не вижу смысла настаивать, что одна нелепая версия чем-то лучше другой :)